# JetBrains Toolbox постоянно вылетает

Tags: ubuntu, jetbrains

На Ubuntu 16.10 JetBrains Toolbox вылетает через несколько секунд после запуска.

- JetBrains Toolbox 1.0.2095
- Node.js 4.2.6
- Oracle Java 8 (1.8.0_111)

Лог не помещается в вопрос, так что Gist: https://gist.github.com/dukeimg/c3430495082a95462fab1ea249bc5b4f

Может, кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если запустить программу с ключом `--disable-gpu`, то всё начинает работать.